# how to igonre a folder which is in root folder while dockerfile is in a sub folder

Tags: docker, visual-studio, dockerfile

I have .git , .vscode and node_modules folder in the root directory and dockerfile inside a build folder as in tree below:

```
.git
.vscode
node_modules
build
  |---dockerfile 
  |--.dockerignore
```

dockerignore looks like this

```
node_modules
../.vs*
../.git
```

and when I run the docker command from the root folder like this

```
docker build   -t dtest_sec  -f .\build\Dockerfile .
```

I am getting error which says it is trying to paccess thr file inside .vs folder so can't build the dockerimage.
I am looking a way to ignore those files but seems not working, can someone show me right way to ignore those files?

Comment: Try moving the `.dockerignore` up one level, and removing the `../`-prefixes.

Comment: that worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are running the command

```
docker build   -t dtest_sec  -f .\build\Dockerfile .
```

Are you aware about the meaning of the last dot? That is the docker build context. Docker sends all files within the context to the docker host to get the container built. If you do not need these files anyway, you could set the build context to be the `build` directory like so:

```
docker build   -t dtest_sec  -f .\build\Dockerfile .\build
```

See also https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/